# Django lookup_expr for arrayfield not matching exact string

Tags: django

I have a djago array field,

```
names = ArrayField(
    CICharField(max_length=255),
    blank=True,
    null=True,
    help_text="Additional names of the person.",
)
```

It has names,

```
"names": [
        "Adam Bender",
        "April Watkins",
        "Daniel Brooks",
        "George Booker"
      ]
```

When I do,

```
    names = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr="icontains")
```

and search for "Adam Bender" it matches the record.
But when I search for "Adam Bend" then also it is matching.
I don't want that to happened. It should match exact name.
I tried `iexact` but it did not work.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

```
names = django_filters.CharFilter(method='names_filter')

def names_filter(self, queryset, name, value):
    return queryset.filter(names__contains=[value])
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use [exact](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#exact) instead of [iexact](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#iexact).

[exact](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#exact) will return you the exact match.

```
Entry.objects.get(id__exact=14)
SELECT ... WHERE id = 14;
```

[iexact](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#iexact) use the like operator to match the results.

```
Blog.objects.get(name__iexact='beatles blog')
SELECT ... WHERE name ILIKE 'beatles blog';
```